# PayPal next_billing_time always return 10:00:00Z

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I've created a PayPal subscription which have a Daily Plan using the following configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Daily plan",
    "description": "Daily plan",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "usage_type": "LICENSED",
    "product_id": "PROD-32M79039A8219464Y",
    "billing_cycles": [
        {
            "frequency": {
                "interval_unit": "DAY",
                "interval_count": 1
            },
            "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
            "sequence": 1,
            "total_cycles": 0,
            "pricing_scheme": {
                "fixed_price": {
                    "value": "5.99",
                    "currency_code": "EUR"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "payment_preferences": {
        "auto_bill_outstanding": false,
        "setup_fee": {
            "value": "0.00",
            "currency_code": "EUR"
        },
        "setup_fee_failure_action": "CANCEL",
        "payment_failure_threshold": 0
    },
    "taxes": {
        "percentage": "0",
        "inclusive": false
    }
}
```

I've created a PayPal subscription which have a Daily Plan using the following configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Daily plan",
    "description": "Daily plan",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "usage_type": "LICENSED",
    "product_id": "PROD-32M79039A8219464Y",
    "billing_cycles": [
        {
            "frequency": {
                "interval_unit": "DAY",
                "interval_count": 1
            },
            "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
            "sequence": 1,
            "total_cycles": 0,
            "pricing_scheme": {
                "fixed_price": {
                    "value": "5.99",
                    "currency_code": "EUR"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "payment_preferences": {
        "auto_bill_outstanding": false,
        "setup_fee": {
            "value": "0.00",
            "currency_code": "EUR"
        },
        "setup_fee_failure_action": "CANCEL",
        "payment_failure_threshold": 0
    },
    "taxes": {
        "percentage": "0",
        "inclusive": false
    }
}
```

So essentially the user must be charged each day for €5.99

I subscribed to this plan on 14-05-2020 17:56:07. Today I should receive the renew, but when I ge the subscription details I see:

```
"next_billing_time": "2020-05-15T10:00:00Z",
```

this date is already passed, is that a timezone problem or there is something wrong on the `PayPal` side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct as 10:00:00Z is when PayPal run the transaction batch.

I had this questions and asked PayPal support for this because need payment attempt at specific time. The following are replicas of our dialogue:

next_billing_time always 10:00:00Z. should it be so?

> Yes, this is correct as 10:00:00Z is when we run the transaction batch.

Subscription created time always 07:00:00Z . should it be so?

> Subscription created time is different from next_billing_time. Next_billing_time will be when the customer is
> billed.